# How to choose correct image resolution for android

Tags: android, uiimage

I have been battling with this for a couple of days. I am trying to write a small custom rating bar. With some custom images. When I check the image I have on my HTC Desire, the image looks horribly aliased. I have tried using different resolutions and different sizes and still can't figure out what resolution/how to create a good quality.

I have read the guidelines on the android site but, to no avail. I think the problem I am having is displaying lower resolution images on a higher dpi display. So the system upscales the image. But I am not sure how to fix that. Higher resolution images? Larger images?

Any advice would be great.

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is a bit of a challenge to get right is the wide variety of screen-resolutions and -densities of Android devices. Fortunately the Android SDK has pretty extensive support in this department. A very good start is [this section](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) of the Android Dev Guide.

Basically you need to understand the concept of *Density-independent pixels (dp)* and use classes like [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) to calculate actual *screen pixels*. And yes, obviously you'll need larger, higher resolution images for higher density screens.

Comment: One of the things is that I don't explicitly set pictures in my code I used. I have created a style that inherits from one of the android progress bar style. Then add custom images using <layer-list>